# Is it possible to force the browser to use only the datalist values in form inputs?

Tags: html

If I use the `datalist` feature in form inputs I will show a list of suggested matches when starting to type values in the input field. The code below illustrates how this can be used.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="action.php">
  <input list="browsers" name="browsers">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When typing *"M"* it will show "Chrome" since it's the only matched option. However, if I enter *"My browser"* and pressing submit it will remember my entered value. Next time I get to the input field and press *"M"* it will show the following:

[image: Form also uses "remembered" inputs]

I.e. it includes the remembered *"My browser"*, and I don't want it to be showed...

**Question**: Is it possible to force the browser to hide/ignore the remembered values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the autocomplete of text in forms, use the autocomplete attribute of  and  elements. You'll need the "off" value of this attribute.

This can be done in a  for a complete form or for specific  elements:

Add autocomplete="off" onto the  element to disable autocomplete for the entire form.
Add autocomplete="off" for a specific  element of the form.

```css
input {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/form/submit" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="Surname" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" name="Credit card number" placeholder="Credit card number">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah, of course... That was easy. I should have found it ;-) . Thanks